# Image with maximum width or height of image itself with saved aspect ratio, restricted by window size

Tags: html, css

I need an image that will save its aspect ratio, will be maximum width or height of image itself, but no more that window height/width.

Here is codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeQqOv

This examples is user avatars and user can load it of any size, but i want for big avatars to have 100% size of image and not stretch on big screens for a small one.

Problem now that small image will stretch.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit: contain;
   max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution that only doesn't have max-height:100vh

```
img {
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to support old browsers, use `object-fit` with the value `contain` which increases or decreases the size of the image to fill the box whilst preserving its aspect-ratio.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

[can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

Comment: Thanks, but small image still stretch

Comment: Personally, I would look to introduce different style rules for small images. I wouldn't expect a small, square, image to behave the same way as a large, landscape, image.

Comment: problem is that it's user avatar and user can load it of any size, but i want for big avatars to have 100% size and not stretch on big screens a small one :(

Comment: An avatar of any size!!?? Weird. I wouldn't want to allow that. Ah well. I suppose you could write some code to determine the size and apply different styles.